# To reduce quardatic form to cononical form by orthogonal method

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

$2(x_1)^2+2(x_2)^2+2(x_3)^2+2x_1x_3$
Image for original question --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmb2i.jpg

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I am often willing to help with even very simple questions, but I wouldn't help with this until you tell us the matrix you looked at, its eigenvalues, and the corresponding eigenvectors.